# How to print current date on python3?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

From what I gather, [here](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html) (for example), this should print the current year in two digits

```
print (datetime.strftime("%y"))
```

However, I get this error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

So I tried to this

```
print (datetime.strftime(datetime.date()))
```

to get

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument
```

so I placed `"%y"` inside of thr `date()` above to get

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'
```

Which start to seem really loopy and fishy to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now.year)
```

The above code works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 28):

The following seems to work:

```
import datetime
print (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y"))
```

The datetime.data object that it wants is on the "left" of the dot rather than the right. You need an instance of the datetime to call the method on, which you get through now()

Answer (score 11):

I use this which is standard for every time

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Current date and time : ")
print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 8):

The built-in `datetime` module contains many functions for getting the specific time and date:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from math import floor

now = datetime.now()

year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day

hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
second = now.second
millisecond = floor(datetime.now().microsecond / 1000)
microsecond = now.microsecond

date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

time24Hour = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
time12Hour = now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: A really handy function. May I suggest you include the 'Argument / Meaning / Example output' information in the code as comments so the function and notes can all be copied as a block?

Answer (score 5):

I always use this code, which print the year to second in a tuple

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

time_now = (now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)

print(time_now)
```